# Re-run PHP rss feed

Tags: javascript, php

I couldn't really find anything online for what I was looking for.
Currently, I have some php code that grabs news feeds and every time the loop runs through, it stores it in an array slot {0,1,2} etc. The interesting part is, I don't know how to refresh the php rss grab function without refreshing the page.

Essentially I have index.php, and  with code inside, and I'd like to re-run the php script in those arrows <> through javascript.
I know in javascript you can assign script names and call them in html, that's essential what I want to do but for php, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your RSS fetching logic is intertwined with your presentation logic. You need to separate them so the RSS logic can be called independently.

Consider a structure like this:

- rss.php - script with logic to fetch RSS feed and package it up as PHP array
- index.php - `require`(s) rss.php and wraps the results in HTML
- api.php - another script which `require`(s) rss.php, but responds with JSON data that can be consumed by Javascript

Now you can present the RSS data when the page loads and then periodically call api.php via Javascript to update the results.

You could also forgo calling rss.php from index.php, merely have it present an HTML skeleton with the javascript and when the page loads, have the javascript call api.php right away to build the initial list. That way you don't have the presentation logic in two places.

Comment: Well, actually my php doesn't display any information currently but rather just records it, the javascript is what displays the text. Thanks for the input though, I'll put it in a seperate php file :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language, meaning your script will be run by the server before it is returned to your client (the browser).

What you can do if you want to continuously get new data from your script is call your server periodically with JavaScript using an AJAX call and display that to your user.

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp).